# Terminal ImportError: No module named pyscreenshot

Tags: python, ubuntu, importerror

while running a python file with the terminal the following ImportError occurs:
ImportError: No module named pyscreenshot

if I run it with spyder everything works fine...

I dont know why this ImportError occurs and how to fix it.
Also I execute the python file in the terminal with sudo.. if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It means that in your terminal's main python version not installed `pyscreenshot` so you can install it with `pip install pyscreenshot` It seems your terminal and spyder using different python files.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be, that you have different versions of python in your system. The version the spyder is using has pyscreenshot installed in it, however the terminal version does not have it. Check which version is being used in both the cases.